# Effect on webmethods code due to webmethods and windows server upgrade

Tags: webmethods

How will my softwareAG code will be affected due to upgrading webmethods 9.6 hosted on windows server 2008 R2 to webmethods 9.12 hosted on windows server 2012 R2

Comment: You listed the same platform and version of the software twice. Based on that transition, I'd expect full functionality.

Comment: My Apologies. Upgrading webmethods 9.6 hosted on windows server 2008 R2 to webmethods 9.12 hosted on windows server 2012 R2

Answer (score 1):

Generally there shouldn't be any effect at the OS level. WIN 2012 R2 is supported with the version 9.12. 
Refer to: https://documentation.softwareag.com/webmethods/wmsuites/wmsuite9-12/SysReqs_Installation_and_Upgrade/9-12_System_Requirements.pdf

I would check the installation and upgrade documentations for details that you need to address during upgrade.